# Storing uploaded product's images in RDBMS

Tags: database-design, relational-database, image-uploading, rdbms

A user can add some product into system. A product can have from 1 to 5 pictures. Picture should remain in system even if users delete them, pictures should be marked as deleted for history.

What is better approach to store links to uploaded products images in RDBMS?

- in products table + 5 columns(picture1_url, picture2_url, ...)
- in separately table product_pictures
- ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not option 1

Use option 2, or option 3 would be a table just for pictures and a many2many table linking products and pictures

You should use the "history table" pattern for deletion, i.e. create a pictures_history table and move pictures there upon delete

Comment: pictures table has foreign key to products table, should we add this foreign key also in pictures_history table?

Comment: Nope no foreign keys on history table

Comment: How will be the SQL for option 2, if I want to extract a product and all images for each product?

Comment: select product_id, product_name, image, whatever_other_data from product join product_image on product_image.product_id=product.product_id. Or more likely in a real app, you'd have two queries: one to get the product info and display that, another to get the images.

Comment: But this select will return 5 rows, and info about product will be duplicated. I want to return 1 row.

Comment: Why is more likely in real app to do 2 queries?